# Issue in domain verification on google cloud platform

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

need help on issue with domain verification on Google cloud platform. I am trying to verify my appspot.comweb url using HTML Tag method. My html contains:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="39k6VaTYfQcrqMGTZ1LDYXxlR4T0gtGeOTce68idUE0" />
<title> This is title </title>
</head>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

I have named it as index.html and using this html file in main.py as below :

```
import logging
from flask import Flask,render_template
from flask import request
import os
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)

MESSAGES = []

@app.route('/pubsub/push', methods=['POST'])
def pubsub_push():
    if (request.args.get('token', '') !=
            current_app.config['PUBSUB_VERIFICATION_TOKEN']):
        return 'Invalid request', 400

    envelope = json.loads(request.data.decode('utf-8'))
    payload = base64.b64decode(envelope['message']['data'])

    MESSAGES.append(payload)

    # Returning any 2xx status indicates successful receipt of the message.
    return 'OK', 200


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', messages=MESSAGES)

    data = request.form.get('payload', 'Example payload').encode('utf-8')

    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(
        current_app.config['PROJECT'],
        current_app.config['PUBSUB_TOPIC'])

    publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data)

    return 'OK', 200
```

after "gcloud app deploy" the url https://financelcr.appspot.com/ just prints Hello world and verification is getting failed with message :

```
Verification failed for https://financelcr.appspot.com/ using the Meta tag method (less than a minute ago). Your meta tag is not in the <head> section of your home page.
Verify your ownership of https://financelcr.appspot.com/. Learn more.
```

Please help on how to resolve the issue. trying to set up Object Change Notification on Google Cloud storage and not not able to run "gsutil notification watchbucket https://financelcr.appspot.com/..... " until domain is verified. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the issue. Header need to be below title. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179 has the correct format of html.