# error on command "gsutil notification watchbucket... "

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to setup object change notification. i am trying to run below command :
`gsutil notification watchbucket https://<project_id>.appspot.com/ gs://bucket_name` and getting error :

```
ServiceException: 401 Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://<project_id>.appspot.com
```

I have created service account and gave all permissions:

```
gsutil acl ch -u <project_id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:FC gs://bucket_name
```

Successgfully verified the domain as an owner of url on webmaster. But still getting same problem.
Have seen similar question on StackOverflow but could not find answers. Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't correctly verified the domain. There are a couple of easy mistakes you may have made:

1. It is possible you verified **`http`**`://project.appspot.com` instead of **`https`**`://project.appspot.com`. You can check and fix this on the [search console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home).
2. It is possible you verified the domain using your own Google account but then attempted to use gsutil with a different account, such as a service account. This is particularly easy on a GCE instance as the default credentials will be the instance's service account.  I recommend running gsutil in [cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/) as this uses your real credentials.

Comment: I have verified it using https ://... I can see it corrected added on domains.

Comment: Using Cloud shell only to run gsutil . :( not sure, wat else I am missing :(