# Firestore cloud functions not triggered when deployed from cloud source repository

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I created a google cloud source repository and added the following in main.py (in my root directory)

```
def sample_function(event, context):
    print('inside sample_function')
    return True
```

I deployed the function using the following command:

```
 $ gcloud beta functions deploy sample_function \
   --entry-point sample_function \
   --runtime python37 \
   --source https://source.developers.google.com/projects/project_id/repos/repository_id/moveable-aliases/my_branch_name \
   --region europe-west1 \
   --trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create \
   --timeout 60s \
   --trigger-resource projects/my_project_id/databases/default/documents/finalDb/{orgId}/tasks/{taskId}
```

The function was deployed successfully as shown:

[image]

But the cloud function is not triggered when a document is added at the specified trigger path.I checked the cloud function logs and there was no entry in the log to showcase that the function executed.

What could be the issue? Am I missing something during deployment?

P.S I wrote the similar functions using the inline editor and they seem to work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase-specific triggers (including Firestore) are currently not supported for python and gcloud.

EDIT

gcloud now has support for writing and deploying [Firestore triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore) in all supported languages.

Comment: Oh well. But they seem to work when the same is deployed using the inline code editor. Any idea when this would be supported. I know as you say there is no commitments and timelines, but i felt this is a basic feature which seems missing

Comment: There are no timelines, sorry.

Comment: I wanted to clarify what you mean by not supported as the command,  gcloud functions event-types list, does have firestore listed in it

Comment: I'm not very familiar with gcloud, but I can tell you that it's not yet intended for developers to write Firebase-specific triggers in python.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. BTW doug, love your videos on youtube. Have a good day :)

Comment: Also i wanted to add that there is a documentation on how to do so: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime
Please do specify there that this isn't supported yet in the docs.

Comment: The documentation you're referring to is only for cloud-based functions deployed by gcloud, not Firebase-based functions deployed by the Firebase CLI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177310/discussion-between-adarsh-and-doug-stevenson).

Comment: But now it is supported: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore