# Passing Variables To Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've just finished writing a Google Cloud Function in the Beta Python 3.7 runtime with an HTTP trigger. Now I'm trying to figure out how to pass a string variable to  my function when calling it. I've read the documentation but I haven't found anything on this.

My trigger resembles:

```
https://us-central1-*PROJECT_ID*.cloudfunctions.net/*FUNCTION_NAME*
```

Am I misunderstanding how Cloud Functions work? Can you even pass variables to them?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You'd pass variables to the function the same way you'd pass variables to any URL:

#### 1. Via a `GET` with query parameters:

```
def test(request):
    name = request.args.get('name')
    return f"Hello {name}"
```

```
$ curl -X GET https://us-central1-<PROJECT>.cloudfunctions.net/test?name=World
Hello World
```

#### 2. Via a `POST` with a form:

```
def test(request):
    name = request.form.get('name')
    return f"Hello {name}"
```

```
$ curl -X POST https://us-central1-<PROJECT>.cloudfunctions.net/test -d "name=World"
Hello World
```

#### 3. Via a `POST` with JSON:

```
def test(request):
    name = request.get_json().get('name')
    return f"Hello {name}"
```

```
$ curl -X POST https://us-central1-<PROJECT>.cloudfunctions.net/test -d '{"name":"World"}'
Hello World
```

More details can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks

Comment: Does this work if the system spins up multiple instances each running the cloud function in response to load - can I be sure they all get to handle the request to set a parameter/variable at least once?

Comment: @nsandersen Each request will only be handled by a single instance.

Comment: How would one then pass a parameter/variable to all instances? Make the function write it to shared storage and have it check this periodically, so that the instance receiving it writes it to disk and the rest pick it up a little later?

Comment: Could you describe what the use case is? Instances are short-lived and don't maintain state unless you store it externally (e.g. in a database).

Comment: Use case would be to pass a parameter, for instance a number of retries or a retry interval or an instruction to do something - basically something related to control rather than data to process. I can restart my cloud function, I just saw it as a natural follow-on question to this answer.

Comment: I think the right way to do what you're describing is to set the parameter as an environment variable, and redeploybl whenever it needs to be changed.

Comment: you know how can i pass an array from my .dart file to cloud function which is in index.js