# Google Cloud Function API Parameters not accepting

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api

So I've got a python google cloud function running from an HTTP trigger. For some reason I have to put in a parameter (myfakeinput) in order to trigger this function. I can't find any documentation to see what the function is actually and what formatting is required. I've tried adding in a second parameter but have had no success and get a 500 error with nothing in the issue log. I've also tried to return 'myfakeinput'  but that also ends up causing a 500 error.

Does anyone know what the value of the parameter being passed in looks like or what its formatting is so I can actually pass in a parameter?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Variables To Google Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233949/passing-variables-to-google-cloud-functions)

Comment: I don't understand your issue and what you want to achieve....

Comment: @DustinIngram yes, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a look at this [documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http#code_sample).

```
from flask import escape

def hello_http(request):
    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args

    if request_json and 'name' in request_json:
        name = request_json['name']
    elif request_args and 'name' in request_args:
        name = request_args['name']
    else:
        name = 'World'
    return 'Hello {}!'.format(escape(name))
```

So "flask" make available to your code the object "request". In the above code, a list of the arguments is then extracted from the object and put into the variable "request_args".

```
request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
request_args = request.args
```

Hope this helps,

Frederic