# Problem with HTTP trigger with Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, http, google-cloud-platform, triggers, google-cloud-functions

This is my code

```
import json
from flask import escape
def location_sort(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    location = json.dumps(request_json)
    location = json.loads(location)
    reverse_location = {v: k for k, v in location.items()}


    x = location.keys()
    harf_x = (float(max(x)) + float(min(x))) / 2 

    y_right = []
    y_left = []
    sorted_location = [] 


    for i in location:
        if float(i) < harf_x:
            y_left.append(location[i])
        else: 
            y_right.append(location[i])

    y_left.sort() 
    y_right.sort(reverse=True) 

    sorted_input = y_left + y_right 


    for i in sorted_input:
        sorted_location.append([reverse_location[i], i])
    for i in sorted_location:
        i[0],i[1] = float(i[0]),float(i[1])
    return sorted_location

def cal_centroid(location):
    area = 0 # 면적
    centroid_x = 0 
    centroid_y = 0 
    temp = 0

    for i in range(len(location)):
        if i == len(location)-1: 
            temp = location[i][0]*location[0][1] - location[0][0]*location[i][1]
            area += temp*0.5
            centroid_x += (location[i][0] + location[0][0]) * temp
            centroid_y += (location[i][1] + location[0][1]) * temp
        else:
            temp = location[i][0]*location[i+1][1] - location[i+1][0]*location[i][1]
            area += temp*0.5
            centroid_x += (location[i][0] + location[i+1][0]) * temp
            centroid_y += (location[i][1] + location[i+1][1]) * temp

    centroid_x = round(centroid_x / (6*area), 6)
    centroid_y = round(centroid_y / (6*area), 6)
    x = [centroid_x, centroid_y]
    return json.dumps(x)

def main(request):
    a = location_sort(request)
    return cal_centroid(a)
```

And i run my code with main. With testing code on google cloud functions, i can just input parameters using trigger event box. But i want to put parameters in using url. Like below.

```
https://YOUR_REGION-YOUR_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME?request={"37.284213":"127.006481","37.562045":"127.034809","37.528694":"126.907483","37.411124":"127.124356"}
```

How should i change my code to act like that? I have difficulties understanding Google docs about Google Functions. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make a POST request with the JSON in the request body instead of a URL parameter. For example, with `curl`:

```
curl -X POST https://YOUR_REGION-YOUR_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d '{"37.284213":"127.006481","37.562045":"127.034809","37.528694":"126.907483","37.411124":"127.124356"}'
```

Comment: If i want to use URL parameter, how can i change my code?? I uploaded another question for it with some change in my code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233949/passing-variables-to-google-cloud-functions/52236286

Comment: Your code parses the JSON POSTed body `request.get_json()`. Instead of this, you have to get the url arg, as mentioned in the @DustinIngram link: `name = request.args.get('name')`.