# How can I return a Google Cloud Python backend output to my flutter app?

Tags: python, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a python backend that takes in an input and returns the result as a json file. I am currently stuck at not knowing how to actually call the function, which is hosted on Google Cloud, in my Flutter app using the function url. I currently do not understand the following issues:-

1. How can I pass an argument to my cloud function via Flutter? Is the functionurl = "https://google-provided-function-url/?query=$query" in flutter the only method to do so? Or do I have other options?
2. The python code will return a json file, which I presume will be sent back as a http.Response type output. In which case, can I simply use json.Decode(response.body) to receive the json? Or should I use convert.jsonDecode(response.body)? Which of the two is correct?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The /? in your question is strange. It's not the standard format of Cloud Function. Are you sure of your URL?

Comment: I assumed it was the correct syntax for passing arguments to a cloud hosted function, going by some of the online examples I referred to.

Comment: the Cloud Functions pattern is the following: `https://<region>-<projectID>.cloudfunctions.net/<functionName>`. It doesn't end with a `/`, thus my comment!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Variables To Google Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233949/passing-variables-to-google-cloud-functions)

Comment: Yes, it answers my question. Please add it as an answer.